# In Which Case Is createdDateTime After lastModifiedDateTime in Microsoft Graph API For Emails?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

**The Background:**

We have a shared mailbox that is being used on both Outlook web and Outlook native apps. We have `created` change notifications set up for emails on it.

I am using Microsoft Graph API v1.0 for reading its emails using this [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}
```

This endpoint returns 4 `dateTime` fields and here's my understanding of them:

```
  "sentDateTime" -         Time when sending server sent that email.
  "receivedDateTime" -     Time when receiving server got that email.
  "createdDateTime" -      Time when email was created in the mailbox's folder.
  "lastModifiedDateTime" - Time when that email was last modified (this changes when email is moved between folders).
```

Recently I came across a scenario that shook my understanding of these fields. I received a notification (I have subscriptions enabled) from Graph API and after querying the above endpoint with that ID, I got these details:

```
  "sentDateTime":         "2023-02-15T17:45:29Z"
  "receivedDateTime":     "2023-02-15T17:45:32Z"
  "createdDateTime":      "2023-03-20T12:29:13Z"
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-02-15T17:45:32Z"
```

Notice that the `createdDateTime` is somehow LATER than the `lastModifiedDateTime`, which doesn't seem possible to me, since the `lastModifiedDateTime` has to change if there's any change in that email.

**The Question:**

So what could have caused this behavior from Microsoft Graph API - `createdDateTime` too much later than `lastModifiedDateTime`?

I posted the same question on Microsoft Learn - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1192105/in-which-case-is-createddatetime-after-lastmodifie).

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you look at that message with MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: Is there a chance dates were changed in Exchange or any other client application such as Outlook?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Unfortunately I don't have access to that mailbox since it is a Production account. Moreover even if I had, I don't think I would be allowed to use OutlookSpy on it :(

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev That was my first thought, but even the Graph's Update Message endpoint has no way to change `createdDateTime` field. This whole scenario just doesn't make sense -- Our app gets a Created Change Notification after a month, without any changes to `lastModifiedDateTime`. My gut feeling says that this has something to do with Syncing done by Native Outlook app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I discovered that when a user creates an email rule in the Outlook PC client and immediately executes the rule to apply it to previous emails, the email's ID gets changed, resulting in a modification of the createdDateTime. This appears to be a bug on the part of Microsoft.

Comment: In the web Outlook, it did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph doesn't alter any data when the [Get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call is made. Make sure that properties are not changed on the server (Exchange) or any client side. You may try to use any low-level explorer tool such as [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or OutlookSpy for exploring internals of mail profiles.

Comment: That is the question - Which scenario may allow changes to `createdDateTime` but not to `lastModifiedDateTime`? Is it even possible on any side (server or client)?

Comment: I guess somebody programmatically could do that. Everything else is out of my understanding.